# Angular JS $http.success() vs $q.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out promises... What is the difference between simply making an $http request, then acting upon whether is what successful (.success()) & it failing (.fail()), in comparison to a promise (q = $q.defer()) with q.resolve()?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How are you making a `$http` request with `$q.defer`? If you don't make a request, then that's obviously the difference.

Answer (score 3):

`$http` itself uses `$q`. These both services are not operating at the same level.

`$http.get(url)` returns a promise that can be resolved or rejected. It means that you are using a promise delivered by a service ($http). Internally, `$http` will call `$q.defer()`, then `$q.resolve()` or `$q.reject()`. This will call either your `.success()` or `.fail()` method.

`$q` is a service to create your own promise.

Using `$q` is a great way to learn about promises but in your case, `$http` is already doing that work for you.

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error/fail have been deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: Yes, success and error/fail have been deprecated in favor of then. But the core answer stays the same. `$http` returns a promise and `$q` "creates" a promise. Within `then()` you still have two callback functions for success and fail. [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. `$http` methods return promises. In short, they can also be chained with `then`. `success` and `fail` are sugar for resolve-only and reject-only `then`s.