# Angular $http.get request not running success or error functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-promise, angular-http

I am trying to make a get request to the nutritionix v1_1 api.  When debugging I can see that the function is successfully called and the correct data is passed in.  When the function hits the `$http.get` request it skips over the rest of the code(the `.success` and `.error` parts), and it doesn't return the promise.  I know the request is good because I have made successful requests using postman.  I have the request written like:

(This method is inside of a factory.  It is later called from a controller.)

```
let getNutrients = (foodId) => {
    let authPart =`appId=${NUTRITIONIXAPIKEY.appId}&appKey=${NUTRITIONIXAPIKEY.appKey}`;
    let filter = 'fields=item_name,item_id,brand_name,brand_id,item_type,nf_calories,nf_total_carbohydrate,nf_dietary_fiber,nf_cholesterol,nf_total_fat,nf_sugars,nf_sodium,nf_protein,images_front_full_url,nf_serving_size_qty,nf_serving_size_unit,nf_servings_per_container';
    // let sort = 'sort: {"field":"_score", "order":"desc"}';
    // let typefilter = '"filters":{"not": {"item_type":3}}';
    return (
        $q((resolve,reject) =>{             
            $http.get(`https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=${foodId}&${filter}&${authPart}`)
            .success( (response) => {
                console.log('nutrix response nutrients request', response);
                resolve(response);
            }).error(function(errorResponse){
                console.log('nutrix fail nutrients request', errorResponse);
                reject(errorResponse);
            });
        })
    );
};
```

here is the factory method call from the controller:

```
NutrixFactory.getNutrients(foodId).then(function(nutrients){
    console.log('nutrients returned', nutrients);
    // $scope.nutrients = $scope.nutrients || [];
    $scope.nutrients.push(nutrients);
    console.log('nutrients array', $scope.nutrients);
});
```

Comment: Why are using $q again? because $http also uses $q

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193217/angular-js-http-success-vs-q-resolve

Comment: @ShankarShastri I don't have a solid answer for that.  It's how I was taught to make the request.  I think it might have something to do with MVC.  I am calling this function from a controller then chaining a .then on the function call to process the returned data.

Comment: Which Version Of Angular?

Comment: @ShankarShastri version 1.5.8

Comment: If you watch your network, does the HTTP request actually get made/return?

Comment: because in angular 1.6 $http.get(url).success is removed.Instead $http.get(url).then is used

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b54a39e2029005e0572fbd2ac0e8f6a4e5d69014

Comment: @ShankarShastri I'm going to try altering the request by removing the encapsulating $q promise and just returning the response in the .success or .error functions.

Comment: that should work I guess...

Comment: @Daniel it does make the request but it has a status of pending

Comment: @tks2n Angular will only run your callbacks once the request completes. You may be looking in the wrong place for your problem...

Comment: @Daniel  I'm looking at the syntax of the angular promise and get request.     Where do you think the issue is?

Comment: @tks2n Well, if your request is getting sent by the client, but never completely returns from the server, it could be in any number of places... Maybe postman is sending a cookie or some kind of authentication that your client isn't, and that's causing the request to stall. Maybe there's something wrong with the enconding or parameters. All I'm saying is that the angular request code might not be the problem, although I do agree with using `.then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try then and catch instated of success and error if its 1.6.*

[Deprecation Notice](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

```
let getNutrients = (foodId) => {
    let authPart =`appId=${NUTRITIONIXAPIKEY.appId}&appKey=${NUTRITIONIXAPIKEY.appKey}`;
    let filter = 'fields=item_name,item_id,brand_name,brand_id,item_type,nf_calories,nf_total_carbohydrate,nf_dietary_fiber,nf_cholesterol,nf_total_fat,nf_sugars,nf_sodium,nf_protein,images_front_full_url,nf_serving_size_qty,nf_serving_size_unit,nf_servings_per_container';
    // let sort = 'sort: {"field":"_score", "order":"desc"}';
    // let typefilter = '"filters":{"not": {"item_type":3}}';
    return (
        $q((resolve,reject) =>{             
           return $http.get(`https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=${foodId}&${filter}&${authPart}`)
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log('nutrix response nutrients request', response);
                resolve(response);
            }).catch(function(errorResponse){
                console.log('nutrix fail nutrients request', errorResponse);
                reject(errorResponse);
            });
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Even if it's pre 1.6.x should still use `.then()` and `.catch()`